# Number of ways a sub committee can be formed

Tags: combinations

Twelve doctors are to be selected by hospital staff to sit on a six-person committee. Within that committee, an additional subcommittee of three doctors will be formed. How many unique sub-committees are possible?...... Please let me know

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: i think so basically in the end the question implies that "no of unique committee of 3 guys from 12 " which is equal to 12C3 ...correct me if am wrong...
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we want the number of unique subcommittees we know that there are ${12\choose 3}=220$ unique subcommittees. The reason we know this is because in total there are $12$ doctors and a subcommittee has $3$ doctors in it. We want all of the unordered selections of $3$ of the $12$ doctors.

Comment: You're welcome! :) It was an interesting problem.

Comment: yeah the question misguides you in thinking that we should first find no of **committees** i.e 12C3 , multiply by number  of unique 3 guys **sub-committee** 6c3 ...but actually its not that case...
do you know any such problem where this **sort of** nesting of committees it would have depended on each other?

Comment: If they asked for how many different committees with subcommittees of the specified sizes we would know that there are ${12\choose 6}\cdot{6\choose 3} committees with subcommittees. In combinatorics there are similar identities where a committee argument can be used to prove the validity of an identity. For example the identity $k{n\choose k}=n{n-1\choose k-1}$ and the identity ${r\choose m}\cdot{m\choose k}={r\choose k}\cdot{r-k\choose m-k}$.

Comment: If they asked for how many different committees with subcommittees of the specified sizes we would know that there are ${12\choose 6}{6\choose 3}$ committees with subcommittees. In combinatorics there are similar identities where a committee argument can be used to prove the validity of an identity. For example the identity $k{n\choose k}=n{n-1\choose k-1}$ and the identity ${r\choose m}{m\choose k}={r\choose k}{r-k\choose m-k}$.

Answer (score 0):

We use the product rule, first there are ${{12}\choose{6}}$ ways of forming six-person committees. From each six-person committee, ${{6}\choose{3}}$ sub-committees can be formed.

Hence, by the product rule, the total number of committees is ${{12}\choose{6}}{{6}\choose{3}}$!

Comment: but this will lead to duplication right!? coz the same 3 guys sub committee can be formed for different combinations of 6 guys committee...so there will be duplication....leme know what are your thoughts!?

Comment: That is correct. Consider the two sets with $6$ doctors $\{d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_6\}$ and $\{d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_7\}$. There are subsets of $3$ doctors that are the same for both of these sets. Using the Multiplication Principle like this leads to over counting. We need the subsets of size $3$ to be unique.